# Does Separation follow from Replacement if Replacement is written using a total function?

Tags: set-theory

If the Axiom Schema of Replacement is written as

$$
\forall \vec{w} \forall A(\forall x(x\in A \implies \exists!y \phi) \implies \exists B \forall y(y\in B \iff \exists x(x\in A \land \phi)))
$$
With $\phi$ having free variables amongst $\{x, y, A, \vec{w}\}$ (but excluding $B$)

and Axiom Schema of Separation is written as

$$
\forall \vec{w}\forall A \exists B \forall x(x\in B\iff (x\in A \land \psi))
$$
with $\psi$ having free variables amongst $\{x, A, \vec{w}\}$ (but excluding $B$)

If so how does the proof work?

Then does Separation follow from Replacement? I've seen a proof using $\phi \equiv \psi \land x=y$ and I can see how that works if $\phi$ is a "partial function" but I can't see how it works when $\phi$ is a total function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is well known that separation follows from replacement.

Define $\xi(x, y)$ to be $(\neg \phi(x) \land y = \emptyset) \lor (\phi(x) \land y = \{x\})$. Then $\{x \in A \mid \phi(x)\}$ can be constructed as $\bigcup \{y \mid \exists x \in A (\xi(x, y))\}$ using the axiom scheme of replacement and the axiom of union.

Note that this proof uses the law of excluded middle. It isn’t possible to prove this without excluded middle.

Comment: I guess for this proof the axiom of pairing is also required to show $\{x\}$ is a set if $x$ is? But that should be ok because I think replacement and power set also implies pairing?

Comment: @Jagerber48 Actually, something I didn’t mention is that we require the empty set to exist. Once we have that, you are correct that we can use power set to construct $\{\phi\}$ and then replacement to construct $\{x\}$. Or we could use pairing to construct $\{x\}$.

Comment: It's a bit of a funny trick. For example, if $S=\{1, 2, 3, 4 \}$ and we want $\{x\in S: x \text{ is even}\}$ we first construct $B' = \{\emptyset, \{2\}, \{4\}\}$. We have to do include the empty set and the set nesting because that function that maps $S$ to $B'$ must be total so $1$ and $3$ need to map to **something** and we choose that **something** to be $\emptyset$. Then we do $\bigcup B' = B=\{2, 4\}$ to remove $\emptyset$ and the nesting. However, if the function could be partial that burden would be lifted and we could directly map $S\to B$, just leaving 1 and 3 "unmapped".

Comment: This reveals the motivation for defining replacement using a partial rather than total function. I believe in this approach you can extract the empty set from any set, something you can't do with the total function.

Comment: @Jagerber48 Yes, this is correct. With the partial function version of replacement, separation follows trivially. From separation, we can take any set $A$ and construct $\emptyset = \{x \in A \mid \bot\}$. However, in intuitionist contexts, there are good reasons to stick with the total function version of replacement. You get this version of replacement “for free” in a sense (actually, you get strong collection, which is stronger), but you definitely don’t get separation for free. Typically, you would always allow $\Delta_0$ separation even when working in a weak set theory.